# How to pass a Callable object in c++17 to be used with std::invoke

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, callable, template-classes

Why the following does not compile when passing `i` to the constructor. The other similar constructs compile.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int RetXPrintU(int x, uint u)
{
    std::cout << "RetXprintU(): " << u << std::endl;
    return x;
}

template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
void Call(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args)
{
    std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fun), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
class CallableObj
{
public:
    explicit CallableObj(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fun), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    std::invoke(RetXPrintU, i, 8u);
    Call(RetXPrintU, i, 8u);
    CallableObj co(RetXPrintU, i, 8u); // WHY I DO NOT COMPILE?
    //CallableObj co(RetXPrintU, 0, 8u); // WHY I COMPILE?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? did you use `std::forward` ?

Comment: error: class template argument deduction failed: CallableObj co(RetXPrintU, i, 8u);  

error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, the compiler can't deduce the template parameters for `CallableObj`. You need add a deduction guide for that:

```
template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
CallableObj(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args) -> CallableObj<Fn, Args>...>;
```

The whole code reads:

```
template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
class CallableObj
{
public:
    explicit CallableObj(Fn fun, Args... args)
    {
        std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fun), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
CallableObj(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args) -> CallableObj<Fn, Args...>;
```

As @Jarod42 pointed out there's no need to make the constructor a template itself (as it was in the first version of the answer).

And here is a [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Py9shM) (corrected version by @Jarod42).

I was assuming your code is just a minimal example and you need the class to be a template. If that is not the case you better go with the other solution.

Comment: No need of template constructor: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z3fmiK)

Comment: Looks great. I just do not understand the following part. How does it work? 
`template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
CallableObj(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args) -> CallableObj<std::decay_t<Fn>, std::decay_t<Args>...>;
` Is it a deduction hint?

Comment: This is a c++17 class template deduction guide. It allows the compiler to deduce the class template arguments from the constructor args: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction (See the section "User-defined deduction guides"

Comment: @Jarod42: OK, but you changed the signature of the constructor from forwarding refs to values...

Comment: @florestan: Not necessary values, type given for `CallableObj` (and indeed, with your deduction guide, you also drop l-value reference, so `CallableObj co{[](int&){}, i)` won't work in your version.

Comment: @Jarod: right, i had the wrong template params in the `std::forward`s in the constructor. I updated the post and the live example. Now your example compiles. Thanks

Comment: I meant something like [that](https://godbolt.org/z/SFd1aW). Your forwarding is actually a `std::move`

Comment: Ok, yeah. Right. That's definitely the better solution. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll change the answer.

Comment: In your previous version, `template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
class CallableObj`, `Args...` is unused moreover...

Comment: Right, but as I wrote in the last sentence I was assuming the user needs the class template parameters in his/her real code.

Comment: @florestan Your assumption was correct. I do need the class template parameters otherwise the class is useless. My example was only to simplify my problem, but the real class obviously needs the parameters

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is you need to move the template from the class to the constructor.  When you have

```
template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
class CallableObj
{
public:
    explicit CallableObj(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fun), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

`Args&&...` is not a variadic forwarding reference because it is deduced for the class itself and when you call `CallableObj co(RetXPrintU, i, 8u);` the class is instantiated and the constructor gets stamped out as

```
explicit CallableObj(int(int, unsigned int)&& fun, int&& arg1, unsigned int&& arg2)
```

What we want is

```
class CallableObj
{
public:
    template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
    explicit CallableObj(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fun), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

so that now `Args` will be deduced when the constructor is called and `Args&&` is now a forwarding reference.

The reason `CallableObj co(RetXPrintU, 0, 8u);` worked in your example is because `0` is a prvalue and a prvalue can bind to an rvalue reference.